# C# - Why are prefixes on fields discouraged?

Tags: c#, coding-standards, naming-standards

Back in the old days, we did Hungarian notation.  That's now considered *passé*, and for the most part I don't use it anymore, but I still find use for the `m_` prefix to indicate member fields.

For me, if I'm reading through someone else's code, and I see this:

```
count = 3;
```

I assume that `count` is a variable local to that function and I'm doing something that will be used elsewhere in the function; if I see this:

```
m_count = 3;
```

I immediately realize that I'm updating the state of the object.

The Microsoft style guidelines say that's the wrong way to do things.  I'm supposed to name my non-public fields exactly like temporary variables defined within the function.  No `m_`, not even a simple underscore.

Yes, we can define our own coding style, but then I have to wrestle with various static code analysis tools, to convince them that our way of doing things is OK.

I'm happy to change to the Microsoft style, but I'd kind of like to know *why* things are the way they are.

Why is it now considered bad to be able to tell whether a variable is function local or a member?

P.S. This is very similar to [What is the regarded current best practises regarding the “this” keyword in front of field and methods in c#?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70223/what-is-the-regarded-current-best-practises-regarding-the-this-keyword-in-fron), but I'm asking about `m_` not `this.`

P.P.S. Also see [Why did Microsoft make parameters, local variables and private fields have the same name naming convention?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101258/why-did-microsoft-make-parameters-local-variables-and-private-fields-have-the-s)

Comment: Doesn't C# have the `this` keyword? Couldn't you refer to members using `this`, such as `this.count`?

Comment: Yes, but (1) it's more typing, and (2) it's easy to forget.  If the field is named m_count I don't have to remember to type this.m_count

Comment: it should be *_count*, not *m_count*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the regarded current best practises regarding the "this" keyword in front of field and methods in c#?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70223/what-is-the-regarded-current-best-practises-regarding-the-this-keyword-in-fron)

Comment: The "member" prefix is kind of an *implementation detail*. It distracts your attention from the *problem* domain to the *technical solution* domain which biases your mind when thinking of possible refactorings.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer - sez who?  Or, to be less flippant, please give some concrete proof of why "_" is preferable to "m_".

Comment: Why do you have to remember anything?  The IDE does that by hovering over the variable.

Comment: @Andy - yes but ... there are many situations where I am looking at code outside of the IDE.  Examples - (1) merge tools.  (2) code review tools.  (3) (gasp) printouts.

Comment: The m_ prefix is a C++-ism where it avoids name clashes between fields and methods. In C# this isn't an issue because method names ought to start with upper case, fields with lower case.

Comment: If you're printing code in 2017, you're doing something wrong.  In the other two scenarios, it should be fairly obvious that `count` didn't just appear out of no where since it wasn't declare in the method.  Frankly the "out of IDE" argument is REALLY weak.  Especially since there are even code review tools which work IN the IDE.

Comment: Still relevant [post from Joel](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: @KaseySpeakman Very interesting read. Seems to be an argument in favor of using "kind" hungarian notation, while what's shown above is "type" hungarian notation. What does "m_" add that the IDE doesn't tell you? Whereas the article's "s" and "us" is meta-information not available in the code. That's where it's actually useful. I'd still create an actual type for that, personally, but for simple types it might be more useful to use a naming convention.

Comment: @KevinFee same answer as before - I may not be looking at the code inside the IDE.  And I will add this - even if I'm in the IDE, it's nice to be able to understand the code without having to hover my mouse over everything.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - can you explain further?  Yours is the only reason I've seen for why to not use the prefix and I don't understand it ... (by which I mean, the other things people are saying are reasons why I don't have to use it, which is not the same as why I shouldn't)

Comment: FWIW [this answer in duplicate question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/70273/31260) argues in favor of  "m_" prefix from the perspective of those using IDE, "as soon as you type the little `m` intellisense gives you a list of all of your private variables..."

Comment: @gnat Oh thanks, I'm going to flag that question for closing too, as its primarily opinion based.

Comment: You should use "this." with all class members always instead of any other arbitrary prefix. That is what it is for and it is unambiguous. StyleCop will help you not to forget.

Comment: One final comment; whether you agree with the MS guidelines or not, that's what developers expect in the .Net world, so at the very least the answer can be consistency and to "play nice" with the community.  Just as I'd follow Java conventions if I did Java development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Microsoft make parameters, local variables and private fields have the same name naming convention?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101258/why-did-microsoft-make-parameters-local-variables-and-private-fields-have-the-s)

Comment: Can you link the aforementioned guidelines? I believe all guidelines published by Microsoft regarding naming convention of private fields are obsolete (such as [Design Guidelines for Class Library Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(v=vs.71).aspx), and [Internal Coding Guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brada/2005/01/26/internal-coding-guidelines/)), and the current guidelines ([Framework Design Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/)) don't cover private fields.

Comment: @BettyCrokker if its not local it should start uppercase, if its private it should start with an underscore. What you are saying (van distinguish between count(local) and count(member) is your own fault because members should not be lowercase. And naming is important so if you name 3 variables the same, they aren't descriptive enough

Comment: Microsoft creates new naming guide lines and then, but does not observe them. Just take a look at the reference source for the framework. For me, some kind of prefix (though I do not like `m_`) is a good way to see immediately the scope of a variable (and yes, I prefer short function where that should not be needed, but I have colleagues...). Hovering with the mouse over it is an extra effort.

Comment: In C#, prefix **are totally useless**. Given that, then I really prefer name without prefix as it avoid useless noise. If same name are used, then usually the only place you explicitly need `this.` prefix would be in a constructor when there is a one-to-one mapping between a parameter and a member. In such case since both refer to the same thing, having distinct names is useless. In functions, I would always use a different name if a local variable or a parameter would have the same name as a member. Doing that make the code more readable (for example `newX` for a parameter that update `x`).

Comment: The first question I'd ask about code like that is why the variable `count` doesn't have a genuinely descriptive name.  If it had one then uses of manual things like an `m_` prefix become moot.

Answer (score 24):

When they were working on the API for Windows, Microsoft recommended the use of Hungarian Notation, using 'm_', as well as 'i', 'sz', etc. At the time, this was useful because the IDE wasn't robust enough to show this information to you.

C#, on the other hand, has a very robust IDE from the outset.

So they made the recommendation in [Microsoft's Naming Guidelines for C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members) for public static or protected fields:

```
✓ DO use PascalCasing in field names.
✓ DO name fields using a noun, noun phrase, or adjective.
X DO NOT use a prefix for field names.
```

Now that you can hover over it with your mouse, or press CTRL+K+W, and get all the information about the member, Microsoft came to the determination that prefixes are bad form; they are a manual solution to an already solved problem.

Private fields are specifically excluded from the guidelines, but Microsoft seems to have come to the conclusion that this is the case even for private fields going forward internally, which you can see if you point Resharper at .NET 4.5 or .NET Core.

Use your tools, don't do it manually.

Comment: Same answer as to Andy ...  yes but ... there are many situations where I am looking at code outside of the IDE. Examples - (1) merge tools. (2) code review tools. (3) (gasp) printouts.

Comment: Andy posted literally the same instant I did. I saw the "1 new comment" pop up as I clicked "add answer". As far as those tools, two of them are in the IDE already. Printouts... why are you doing that?

Comment: My initial question remains unanswered ... yes, Microsoft said don't use m_ and tool manufacturers followed that, but that's not a technical reason to use m_, it's what is often called "appeal to authority".  The only technical reason I've seen to not use m_ came from Timothy Truckle and I don't understand it ...

Comment: @BettyCrokker Because m_ adds absolutely no value.  The IDE tells you member or not, so the m_ is redundent.  Any why are you fixated on m_?  Why not l_ (for local)? Why not afsdfjdskfjas_ ?  I'm going to downvote the question, because its a silly religious argument anyway.  Do whatever you want.  The guidelines you're knocking also say "The field-naming guidelines apply to **static public and protected fields**. **Internal and private fields are __not__ covered by guidelines**, and public or protected instance fields are not allowed by the member design guidelines. "

Comment: It adds value to me; it may not add value to you, and that's fine, so you don't have to use it.   Bottom line: m_ adds value to me, and I have not seen any technical reason why it hurts anything.  Thanks for pointing out the "not covered by guidelines", that helps.

Comment: @BettyCrokker You're asking why the authority made the decision that they did. I'm explaining that it's because their IDE does what you want without needing to do it manually. How is showing the authority's guidelines, then explaining them, an appeal to authority?

Comment: If you start with the assumption that everything must be done inside the IDE (and I can understand Microsoft pushing that view, it helps their business) then your conclusion makes sense.  For me, I can't make that assumption.

Comment: @BettyCrokker OK, but you're asking about guidelines that are made with that assumption. You're also complaining about static tools that are likely using that assumption as well, because "no one" (within an acceptable statistical margin of error) prints out their C# code. I don't know what statistical analysis tools you use, but Resharper is pretty specific: Private fields are "_lowerCase". Public members of any type or "UpperCase", and locals are "lowerCase". Saving on the "m" actually looks pretty nice, anyway.

Comment: This answer is misleading and incorrect.

Comment: @FrankHileman Care to provide some more feedback as to what is incorrect and misleading? Just saying that doesn't help me to improve it.

Comment: @KevinFee That's interesting about Resharper using the underscore prefix - where did they get that from?  Is that just something a lot of people do?  I started looking at static code analysis tools, if the underscore is a standard (even an unofficial one) that would satisfy my desire to be able to distinguish local variables from private fields ...

Comment: @BettyCrokker I am unable to find any justification from JetBrains as to why Resharper does that by default. I hardly use private fields, I almost always use get-only or private-set properties instead. You can configure it to instead prefer "this.", or "m_" if you really want it to, but that of course was one of the things you didn't like doing.

Comment: @BettyCrokker the leading underscore is indeed an unofficial standard. You'll see it in *many* C# code bases.

Comment: @KevinFee There is no .net design guideline for private field prefixes. The guidelines are for public members only.

Comment: @FrankHileman Updated to point that out. I didn't do that because it looked like the other answers covered it. Any other incorrect or misleading statements?

Comment: @BettyCrokker The underscore prefix groups private fields together in the alphabetically ordered drop-down lists of members provided in IDE's. They always go to the top of the list.

Comment: @FrankHileman Or you can use the "show only fields" in intellisense...

Comment: @KevinFee If a prefix is used for IntelliSense, then `this.`can be used and the advantage of it is that you can delete it afterward and have clean, beautiful code without extra noise.

Answer (score 16):

C# doesn't have any global variables, so that leaves only local variables and class-fields.

And if you have so many local variables you lose track of whether an identifier is one, you have most assuredly violated one of the guidelines for managing complexity most grievously.

Try to extract a parameter-object, try to split your function in multiple simpler ones, you most certainly should refactor your code unless you like drowning in minutiae and complexity, as well as have no regard for maintainability.

Now that we have established that the purpose of "this-is-a-member"-decorations no longer holds as the function-scope should be too small and the global scope does not exist, there is one disadvantage to those markers: They inhibit moving arguments / local variables to members, or the other way around.

Comment: Once you dot into it, it could also be a class or namespace.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question.

Comment: This doesn't seem related to the question.

Comment: @FrankHileman Actually, it is. It explains why there is no good reason for uglifying a name.

Comment: "uglifying"? If this is the case, it is an opinion-only question. Everyone can have a different opinion about ugliness. There are reasons for preferring one convention over another, but there is no standard convention in this case.

Comment: @FrankHileman: Well, how would you call tacking some random prefix onto a proper descriptive name, if not uglifying? Decorating seems ... inadequate, especially as the addition serves no purpose anymore, and as others said can get in the way of refactoring.

Comment: @Deduplicator beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Conventions I once considered ugly, I now appreciate as useful.

Comment: There's some other cases where prefixes are useful, e.g., not using a prefix for member fields means that properties that need a backing field (and can't be made into auto-properties) are always one casing mistake from a `StackOverflowException`, intellisense doesn't really help with this and will happily autocomplete `something` to `Something` in the getter/setter of `Something`. Since this causes an *instant crash* and produces no warnings from the compiler (would only be caught by unit tests or manual testing), I feel that a prefix is a fair workaround.

Comment: @jrh: Well, that's an obvious case of failure to use an appropriate name for the field. I'm sure there are some for that (as you said) rare case. Also, there are worse things than a guaranteed crash, at least that's obvious enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator To use a random example, let's say the class had a property called `Name` which the class wanted to validate to see if the given name was not a blank string, null, etc -- you would have to have a `name` backing field to store the validated name, as far as I know there's no way to use auto-properties for this. I could call the backing field `validatedName` or `internalName`, but is that really better than an `_`?

Comment: Also, another unrelated case, in a getter that constructs something, modifies properties, and returns it, there's a limited number of useful names you can choose for that local variable you're returning that are unique from the property name.

Comment: @jrh Well, then it seems an exception for properties which need a backing-field just like that might make sense. All access from outside the property will probably still avoid the backing-field. Regarding your second example, if you need to construct something to return it, a mechanistic name for the temporary seems the most appropriate, like `result`.

Answer (score 12):

Why do developers avoid prepending namespaces with the using namespace directive?

`System.DateTime()` is much more explicit than `DateTime()`. It tells me exactly what I'm dealing with. Is it just because we're lazy typists?

No. We are lazy typists, but that's not why.

We prefer coding styles that let us ignore detail and focus on abstractions. Forcing names to communicate structure details is distracting. When I'm working on a complicated algorithm I don't want names that insist on reminding me every little detail about the thing I'm working with. I just need the name to keep me from confusing `Timer` and `DateTime`. I'll worry about if those are compatible somewhere else.

It's the same reason you don't want two guys on your team named Jon. The fact that they have last names is not a reason to give them prefixes or suffixes. I'm just going to call you Skeet. Anything more is a flat out pain.

Comment: This doesn't seem  to answer the question. There is no general preference or convention for private fields in .net.

Comment: @FrankHileman In general, we prefer good names. Conventions do not create good names. Conventions create names like McOhPlease Von StopItAlreadyStine.

Comment: Conventions are just to make it easier to work with different developer's code. Your answer does address hungarian, but there is no convention for private fields, so the question is based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 11):

Let's expand a bit.

There are 3 common prefix styles, all of which are occasionally encountered in c# code:

- m_
- _
- this.

**Such prefixes are commonly used in the private implementation of a class**. The Microsoft recommendation is primarily about the exposed parts of a class.

The advantage of using `m_` over `_` is that the prefix can be the same in your entire codebase if you use c# as well as [languages where using `_`as a prefix is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).* The advantage of `m_` over `this.` is that it's shorter and that you won't accidentally forget about the prefix.

The advantage of `_` over `m_` is that it's shorter and that anything starting with the prefix is sorted at the top is sorted alphabetically by a tool. The advantage of `_` over `this.` is that it's shorter and that you won't accidentally forget about the prefix.

The advantage of `this.` over `m_` and `_`is that you can use it in a codebase where `_` or `m_` are not an accepted and universal convention. That also means nobody needs to know about the `_` or `m_` convention, which can be seen as making things simpler. As a downside, because the compiler doesn't care about this prefix, the `this.` prefix will occasionally be missing, and as such not be as reliable as an indicator.

---

*Once you start accessing C# classes that use `_` from C++/CLI (which really really shouldn't use `_`), you'll notice that agreeing on a common prefix is more complex than it should be. Deciding to not have a prefix gets rid of that noise. Combine this with Deduplicator's answer, which I'll paraphrase as "the advantage of a prefix is almost negligible", and it gives us: *"There's a tiny problem when using prefixes, and a tiny upside, thus it's a valid choice to just not use them".*

---

There's [an older question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659552/why-shouldnt-i-prefix-my-fields) related to this.

Comment: Nice comparison. However, I find that not using any prefix works well in practice.

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that the MS style guide only talks about public and protected methods and variables. ie The ones other devs will see if they use your library.

The idea being that Microsoft libraries are given a standard look and feel to developers consuming them.

You are free to use whatever style you like on your private or local variables.

Having said that variable prefixes are discouraged in general for a number of reasons

- They can be wrong, and hence misleading
- If you are prefixing by variable type its not clear how you handle classes that you have created.
- There are a number of conventions and they don't always agree. What you find helpful another dev might find unhelpful
- In the case of member variables you can use this 'this.' keyword to indicate the scope and the complier will enforce it.

Comment: Originally I used no prefix at all for fields. Later, I switched to using a single "_" character, as I saw others using it because it moves all fields to the top of the alphabetized member list when you use IDE drop-down list boxes. The lack of a standard convention can be annoying when reading code written by many different developers.

Comment: after a while you see so many different styles you just ignore them. If you tried to enforce a style you would be constantly refactoring everything

Comment: If you apply "They can be wrong, and hence misleading" to most anything, you quickly discover that you shouldn't name variables or functions - they might be wrong after all!  And I'm guessing that your second bullet point is supposed to say "classes that you have NOT created"?  Or else I just don't understand it ...  In any case, it's starting to sound like having a single underscore prefix for non-public fields is an unofficial standard, that's probably the direction we will go.

Comment: some things are checked by the compiler, so m_count might not be a member variable, but this.count will always be

Comment: lots of ppl use _ but things change over time, youll find that code written to 'best practice' last year doesnt match this years conventions

Comment: some people prefix ints with i, strings with s etc. but what do you prefix a MyClass with

Comment: @Ewan I still like "_" but I don't try to convince anyone to use it. Fortunately .net does have many conventions that solve many of the formatting disputes; this one is relatively small compared to my C++ days.

Answer (score 5):

> > The "member" prefix is kind of an implementation detail. It distracts your attention from the problem domain to the technical solution domain which biases your mind when thinking of possible refactorings. – me
>
> can you explain further? Yours is the only reason I've seen for why to not use the prefix and I don't understand it ... (by which I mean, the other things people are saying are reasons why I don't have to use it, which is not the same as why I shouldn't) – Betty Crokker

My point is extending the answers of @CandiedOrange and @Ewan.

#### Prefixes make refactoring harder

As your code evolves variables and methods may change their scope. Eg. you may create a private method and later finding out that it should be available to other (new) classes too. Similar may happen to method parameters and local variables.

Let's say you create a Tax calculator. According to the principle of *lease visibility scope* for variables you start with a method that takes both, the *tax rate* and the *base value* as parameters:
<sup>(example may look Java-ish...)</sup>

```
class TaxCalculator{
   double Calculate(double p_TaxRateInpercent, double p_BaseValue){
     return (100+p_TaxRateInpercent)/100 * p_BaseValue;
   }
}
```

next you have to implement the reverse operation and according to TDD you do it with the least effort:

```
class TaxCalculator{
   double Calculate(double p_TaxRateInpercent, double p_BaseValue){
     return (100+p_TaxRateInpercent)/100 * p_BaseValue;
   }
   double CalculateBase(double p_TaxRateInpercent, double p_TaxedValue){
     return p_TaxedValue/((100+p_TaxRateInpercent)/100);
   }
}
```

Next TDD wants you to refactor the code to become cleaner which is to reduce the parameter list of both methods.
<sup>(Yes, you would extract the doubled calculation first, but let me get my point...)</sup>
The obvious solution is to change *tax rate* into a member variable by passing it as a constructor parameter.

```
class TaxCalculator{
   double m_TaxRateInpercent;
   TaxCalculator(double p_TaxRateInpercent){
     m_TaxRateInpercent = p_TaxRateInpercent;
   }
   double Calculate(double p_BaseValue){
     return (100+m_TaxRateInpercent)/100 * p_BaseValue;
   }
   double CalculateBase(double p_TaxedValue){
     return p_TaxedValue/((100+m_TaxRateInpercent)/100);
   }
}
```

As you can see we had to change *all* lines of our existing methods (any line we used `p_TaxRateInpercent` to be exact.

The problem is, that you have *no support from your IDE* to do the renaming throughout the class. The only help it *search/replace* which will also change the constructor or any part that accidentally contains the string `p_TaxRateInpercent`.
<sup>You IDE might offer a *change to ...* refactoring for undefined variable names but this may be restricted to the scope of the method</sup>

Without the prefix only the method signatures would have changed. No renaming would have been needed at all.

---

#### Prefixes clutter SCM history when changed

Also the *SCM* records the change of the prefix as changes in the logic although the logic didn't change! The SCMs history is cluttered with this technical change hiding what is important and raising the risk for conflicts with the (real logic) changes of others.

Answer (score 3):

> For me, if I'm reading through someone else's code, and I see this:
>
> ```
> count = 3;
> ```
>
> I assume that 'count' is a variable local to that function and I'm doing something that will be used elsewhere in the function

And you will be absolutely right ***if* you are reading source code which respects C#'s style conventions.** In such code:

```
this.count = 3;
```

assigns a value to a field.

```
count = 3;
```

assigns a value to a local variable.

Therefore, C#'s style conventions are clear and unambiguous. They force you not to use any prefix **simply because you don't need one.**

As for the source code for which the authors decided to use their personal conventions instead, you should ask *them* personally why they made a choice to do so. If they don't use prefixes such as underscores, while not using `this.` either, it would effectively lead not only to difficult to read code, but also cases where an additional convention would be needed:

```
public class Hello
{
    private string greetings;

    public Hello(string greetings)
    {
        greetings = greetings; // Wait, what is that?!
    }
}
```

> Doesn't C# have the this keyword? Couldn't you refer to members using this, such as this.count?
>
> Yes, but (1) it's more typing, and (2) it's easy to forget. If the field is named m_count I don't have to remember to type this.m_count

Here, however, you're wrong.

It's more typing when you write your code in Notepad. With an IDE with auto-completion or, better, IntelliSense, the comparison between `this.count` and `m_count` is not as obvious. Note the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> required to type the underscore.

As for “easy to forget,” again, this is relevant only for the users of Notepad. Not only StyleCop and Resharper won't let you forget putting `this.` when needed, but after a few hours of programming, putting `this.` when needed becomes a habit.

Comment: I find that using `this` only when you need it results in a really inconsistent feel and distracts me far too often. If you're going to use `this` instead of a prefix, I believe you should *always* use it. In which case, it becomes a prefix and you might as well use `_`.

Comment: RubberDuck is right. "this." is a prefix, although, it does have compiler meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I use _ prefix for all member variables.  I hate 'this' prefix because, while some claim it's the right way of doing things - it adds a lot of noise/clutter to your codebase.  A single underscore is also a common practice in Microsoft's samples.

So in your example I'd have:

```
int _count = 10;
```