# Am I understanding the new C# naming conventions right?

Tags: c#, naming-standards, microsoft, access-modifiers

A couple months ago, Microsoft updated their C# Naming Conventions (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).  As the developers of C#, I consider Microsoft to be the standard for coding conventions.

[image]

They want private and **internal** fields to be named as `_myField`.  So calling an internal field from another class would look like this:

```
internal class MyClass1
{
    internal int _myInt;
}

internal class MyMainClass
{
    private MyClass1 _myClass1 = new MyClass1();

    internal void DoStuff()
    {
        _myClass1._myInt = 5;
    }
}
```

`_myClass1._myInt = 5;` just doesn't feel right to me.  Maybe its because I am used to doing it other ways.

Am I understanding this convention right?  If so, what are the objective benefits to doing it this way opposed to using the common PascalCase for internal fields?  Are there any disadvantages?

---

Related question from Microsoft's convention in 2008, which goes against this new standard:
[C# - Why are prefixes on fields discouraged?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/350906)

Comment: Rule number 1: don't use `internal` fields. Now the problem goes away.

Comment: @PhilipKendall really?  I would think internal fields should be the preference over public.  Maybe that's the question I should be asking.

Comment: I understand the logic behind `internal` fields, but I would still be reluctant to use them.  If I did use them, I would follow the underscore convention.  PascalCase should be reserved for properties.

Comment: Regarding the 2008 convention, underscore is *not a prefix.*  A prefix is something like `strName` or `intName` for a string variable or integer variable, respectively.  `m_` is a prefix, though; it stands for "member variable."  Avoid it, like all other prefixes.

Comment: In other news, I'm glad that Microsoft finally settled on a naming convention for class variables.  Previously, this decision was left up to the original programmer; now that it has become a standard, it can be added to the linting rules for Visual Studio.

Comment: I definitely agree with @PhilipKendall. I've never created an internal field in 20 years of writing C# code. Fields are private; always in my view. If it needs to be internal, make it a property and ideally make it a get-only one at that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Microsoft give with one hand and take with the other. Standardising on `_camelCase` for field names is great. But then they blow their credibility by suggesting that static fields should prefixed with `s_`. I know of no one that does that and it just blows their credibility, encouraging everyone to ignore all their standards.

Comment: Am I completely lame for not like leading underscores, because it is a hard key to reach? I don't even like `snake_case` when it is a commonly accepted naming convention. My pinky just doesn't stretch that far. That whole top row of the keyboard is awkward anyways. Except the `2` and `3` keys. For some reason those aren't so bad.

Comment: @GregBurghardt In my case it's not it being hard to reach (I personally don't find it hard to reach), but I just don't like it and find it unnecessary.

Comment: @MetalMikester - I also echo your sentiment about finding it unnecessary. Sometimes I wish the compiler would force all fields to be private. I'm sure there is that *one* use case where it is necessary to have a non private field, but the OOP bigot in me thinks you should be required to tinker with compiler flags and know what you are doing before making a field anything but private.</rant>

Comment: @GregBurghardt, disliking underscores because they are hard to reach is unusual. Certainly not lame though. Like with spaces v tabs or K&R versus Allman braces, there's a split is style preference in C#: liking and disliking `this`. For the latter group, prefixing a field with `_` makes sense. For the former it serves no purpose. As ever in such debates, neither side is right or wrong, and neither side is lame unless they get sanctimonious and claim theirs is the only correct way.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I fully agree with you and I refuse to use leading underscores (unless work's code style forces me). I find it a variation on Hungarian notation, one which denotes the access modifier instead of the type; but I dislike it for the same principle. Also, it seems Microsoft agrees with us. Reproduce: add `string test` to a constructor, press Alt+Enter, pick _"Create and assign field 'test'"_. What does it generate? `private readonly string test;`. **No underscore.** I rest my case.

Comment: The initial underscore is a strong standard in Objective-C for the backing variable of a propery. You only ever see it in the implementation file. You need it if you write a non-trivial implementation of a getter or setter. It's efficient because it doesn't call an accessor function but goes directly to the member. You only do it when you're sure that nobody overrides the property. Important: The _property_ has no underscore. The property name with underscore is used to access the underlying variable holding the property value.

Comment: @Flater, [that bug in VS is easily fixed](https://ardalis.com/configure-visual-studio-to-name-private-fields-with-underscore/) ;)

Comment: How this wasn't closed because based on comments it is clearly opinion based

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### That's just your opinion, man.

Naming conventions are an inherently subjective convention. There is no technical reason for most naming conventions, other than which characters are allowed to be used in names. To that extent, it's really just a matter of what you prefer.

But then we get to team-based development, and we realize that it's quite annoying if we don't all use the same approach, yet have to share the code. This is why conventions start making their appearance.

I *suspect* Microsoft was thinking of internal fields as assembly-private fields, which they arguably are, and therefore logically concluding that the same naming convention would make sense. However, I agree with your question's claim that there's a difference between the two, because internal field usage syntax is indistinguishable from public field usage syntax, provided the consumer is located in the same assembly. Seeing a private naming convention there rubs me the wrong way.

The short answer here is that Microsoft is just one opinion in a room of many, many opinions. If you want to attach more weight to their opinion, that's perfectly fine, but there are plenty of others who don't and/or outright disagree.

---

Microsoft also contradicts itself. Its code generating tools in VS don't use an underscore prefix even for private fields. You can replicate this behavior:

- Create a class and write a parameterless constructor for it.
- Add a method parameter to the constructor (`string test`).
- With your text cursor on `test`, press Alt+Enter
- Choose "create and assign field 'test'".
- What do you get?

[image]

No underscore. I rest my case.

---

### This is just my opinion, man.

Personally, I don't even like underscore prefixes for private fields to begin with.

In case you've not heard of [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation):

> Hungarian notation is an identifier naming convention in computer programming, in which the name of a variable or function indicates its intention or kind, and in some dialects its type. [..] As the Microsoft Windows division adopted the naming convention, they used the actual data type for naming, and this convention became widely spread through the Windows API; this is sometimes called Systems Hungarian notation.

This naming convention advocates for prepending certain characters to variable names to indicate their type. `sFoo` for strings, `iFoo` for integers, `lFoo` for longs, ...

To quote Douglas Adams, in the beginning Hungarian notation was created. This has made a lot of people very angry and has been widely regarded as a bad move. At the time of writing, Hungarian notation is no longer used.

The best explanation I could find as to why it's a bad solution for the problem it tries to solve can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112068/952296). Some excerpts:

> Hungarian notation only makes sense in languages without user-defined types. In a modern functional or OO-language, you would encode information about the "kind" of value into the datatype or class rather than into the variable name.
>
> Hungarian notations just turns the programmer into a human type-checker, with is the kind of job that is typically better handled by software.
>
> Hungarian notation was specifically invented in the sixties for use in BCPL, a pretty low-level language which didn't do any type checking at all. I dont think any language in general use today have this problem, but the notation lived on as a kind of **cargo cult programming**.
>
> In any other language, hungarian is just ugly, redundant and fragile. It repeats information already known from the type system, and you should not repeat yourself.

I, and I think most developers today, agree with every point made here.

Back to underscore prefixes and why I don't like them. Just like how Hungarian notation denotes the type of a variable, which is pointless for all the reasons mentioned above, I see no reason why denoting the accessibility modifier using a prefix for the name makes any more sense than denoting its type.

The compiler already stops you from accessing something that the access modifier already said you shouldn't be able to access, so there's no added gain from making sure the developer explicitly acknowledges at every turn that he knows this is a private field.

Comment: In C#, interfaces are usually prefixed with `I`, exception types are suffixed with `Exception`, async methods are suffixed with `Async`, generic parameters are prefixed with `T`. In MVC, classes are invariably XxxController, XxxView etc. Hungarian notation is everywhere.  You are therefore clutching at straws with your arguments about `_` for fields. And it's worth pointing out it has nothing to do with accessibility. Fields are typically expected to be private; the `_` denotes it's a field rather than a parameter or local variable.

Comment: And I tend to notice that those that dislike `_` also seem to like `this.` (not universal, but a significant number fit this mould). In my view, `this.` makes Hungarian Notation look sane. But others will disagree with me. So whilst you clearly title your section "This is just my opinion, man", the argument behind your opinion has more holes than a block of emmental cheese.

Comment: @DavidArno: I don't think it's clutching at straws to simply argue that _not everything_ should be baked into the method/field/variable/prop name. It's not all or nothing. The  `I` is due to the high likelihood that an interface and its implementation (in DI) often don't differ in name, and it's shorter than `xxxInterface`. Same argument goes for `T`, it's merely a shortening of something that actually contributes meaningfully. I personally think the `Async` suffix should only be used when both sync and async options are available, to keep the signatures equivalent barring `Async` as suffix.

Comment: @DavidArno: Exceptions are indeed an exception here (hah), but this goes beyond pure naming. Exceptions are the one thing where it's considered acceptable to bank on overzealous downcasting and later having to type check to figure out what the (more) concrete type was again. Usually that's bad OOP, but exceptions are different because it facilitates a behind-the-scenes throwing and catching logic that would otherwise significantly add to the bloat. Could it have been done differently, sure, but this is a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @DavidArno Opinion on global usage of `this.` aside (it's a holy war), `this.` has a concrete benefit in that it enables you to have the same name for your constructor parameter and the field you're going to store it in. Otherwise, you have to come up with some creatively different (read: subjective, distracting, and not meaningfully contributing) name just to make your straightforward field assignment work. Yes, that includes the `_`, in my opinion. At least this way you don't have to carry the `_` in perpetuity. You can use `this.` in case of ambiguity and drop it in all other cases.

Comment: @DavidArno: In short, all supposed counterexamples you mention make a meaningful distinction that contributes to the readability and, more importantly, if absent would cause you to have to come up with variations of the same name to avoid conflicts. But this does not apply to `_`. We could scrub it from every codebase, stick to simple Pascal/camelCase distinctions, use `this.` for the few cases where there's a conflict with a method parameter (mostly constructors), and nothing would get lost in the process.

Comment: Just eves-dropping here but I consider using `I` to prefix standard for interfaces is a really great example of a bad Hungarian wart.  It's completely unnecessary and pretty confused: interfaces are primary.  You should care more about the name of your interface than the name of your class.  It also makes a mess when alphabetically sorting classes and interfaces.  Rather than a counterpoint to your argument, I think it's a good confirmation of it.

Comment: @JimmyJames: Concretely, how would you refactor the names of `class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository`?

Comment: @Flater The direct translation of that to common Java conventions would be an interface named `OrderRepository` and a class named `OrderRepositoryImpl`.  I'm not a huge fan of that though.  A one-to-one relationship between a class and an interface suggests that the interface may not be necessary.  Naming your class as if it will be the only implementation ever is therefore problematic.  If I just need a generic initial implementation, I might name it 'BasicOrderRepository` or maybe 'DefaultOrderRepository' etc. dependin on the use case.

Comment: @JimmyJames: _"A one-to-one relationship between a class and an interface suggests that the interface may not be necessary."_ Therein lies the rub. In a DI context, interfaces are pretty much default, with often the only second implementation being a mocked implementation (which is named differently, usually `MockedFoo : IFoo` compared to `Foo : IFoo`) for the purpose of tests. In those "one real implementation" cases, the interface and its real implementation are nigh indistinguishable, and having to come up with two names for what is essentially the same thing detracts from readability.

Comment: @JimmyJames: As a second example, if the interface is intended to be implemented by different projects and developers, but only one implementation per project (e.g. mods or plugins often do this), it also makes little sense to deviate from the name as defined by the interface. Having to prepend your own custom prefix (which is likely already in your namespace anyway) is smurf naming convention, which detracts from readability.

Comment: @Flater If you really can't think of a better name for `OrderRepository` such as `DatabaseOrderRepository` or `InMemoryOrderRepository` then I suppose `OrderRepositoryImpl` is OK.  But naming an interface like it's an extension of the class is truly backwards.  I get what you are saying about DI and this is part of the problem I have with DI frameworks.  Maybe some of it is a weakness in the language(s).  If classes came had implicit interfaces, a lot of this redundancy dissapears.  Another thing I tend to do is not create public concrete implementations of interfaces at all.

Comment: @JimmyJames Arguments against the `I` prefix which lean on "If DI frameworks were different" or "if C# was different" actually do the opposite - they reinforce the need for it because DI frameworks and the C# language are in fact, the way they are. I agree that in the hypothetical scenario you described we wouldn't need this obvious Hungarian notation that carried over from the COM days, but we code in the real world, so we do need it.

Comment: @JimmyJames: FooImpl (implementation of Foo) and IFoo (interface of Foo) sound like they're alternate equal solutions (one of them has to give) and I don't quite see why one would be worse than the other. Interfaces cannot meaningfully exist without a concrete implementation as they are abstract, so giving the "real" name to the concrete thing makes sense to me, as interfaces are an addition and thus adjust their name based on what was there already.

Comment: Classes implement interfaces, not the other way around. You wouldn't name a parent class `FooParent`, would you? Here's an example of a normal naming heirarchy: `Collection`<-`AbstractionCollection` and from there you have `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. What you are saying is that it's equivalent to name these `LinkedListInterface`<-`AbstractLinkedList`<-`LinkedList`. But clearly that's not the case. That's only true if there's a one-to-one relationship between classes and interfaces. The idea of interfaces is that they are agnostic of their implementation. That's the whole point.

Comment: @JimmyJames Well, no. In the cases of the only difference between a class and interface being the I prefix, the class directly implements the interface, and barring mocks is the only "real" implementor. For multiple real implementors, the interface clearly denotes something more abstract that the concretion, and thus has a name of its own (still with an I prefix, as per C# naming conventions, as a matter of consistency). [..]

Comment: @JimmyJames [..] Having AbstractLinkedList implement LinkedListInterface and then not having LinkedList implement the interface directly is a different situation and not a case I was considering, advocating or focusing on.

Comment: @JimmyJames There is a contextual difference between (a) here's an abstract interface, and implementations will be done later and (b) I'll extract an interface from this concrete class so I can easily mock it. DI-driven single implementor cases fall squarely in (b), where the class precedes the interface. You dismiss this as a valid approach, so it makes sense to you to dismiss the subsequent naming pattern as invalid, but this is actually a very common and conventionalized approach that is just inherently contextually different from (a), where your feedback does make sense.

Comment: @Flater We are way off topic here but I want to clarify one thing: " You dismiss this as a valid approach" I'm sorry that I gave you that impression.  I get why it's necessary for that case and perhaps in that narrow use, it makes sense.  I just think 1) being such a common pattern the language should provide better support.  Classes already have an implicit public interface.  Not having to create redundancies like this is one of the nice things about working in Python.

Comment: @JimmyJames _"Classes already have an implicit public interface"_ Which cannot be decoupled from its implementation, rendering it irrelevant in terms of mocking. "The language should be better" is not a catch-all solution or IMO productive stance in a discussion on naming conventions. The convention is there to work with the language that exists, not the one we wish existed.

Comment: 2) What I've seen in C# codebases is that most developers never create 'real' interfaces.  I get the feeling that they think all interfaces should be named this way.  I think you are agreeing that these are 'degenerate' interfaces and if that's all you ever create, you are missing a big part of OO design.

Comment: @Flater "Which cannot be decoupled from its implementation, rendering it irrelevant in terms of mocking."  What I am saying is that the language could/should be enhanced to support mocking of classes without a separate interface.  This doesn't just apply to C#.

Comment: If you're going to argue that a leading underscore is a form of Hungarian notation and thus is bad, then so is *any* naming convention.  Specifically, using PascalCase for a class property vs camelCase for a method argument.

Comment: From a practical perspective in C#, using PascalCase for properties, camelCase for method arguments, and _camelCase for fields avoids having to litter the code with extra this. noise and prevents the situation of accidentally using fooVariable where this.fooVariable was intended.

Comment: Looks like quantity wins over quality here :)

Answer (score 2):

The question of naming conventions is really opinion based. However, here are a couple of things closely related to your question that are worth discussing.

---

On a more general note, general "industry standard" naming conventions and coding styles (and tools such as various linters, etc.) should be *secondary* to the needs of you and your team, to the way you think about your problem domain, to your needs to express concepts in your design of actual code, and to the specific considerations you as a team have with respect to things like overall skill level, onboarding process, turnover rate, etc.

Following an "industry standard" naming convention (or project/folder structure) is not "more professional" (or less professional) then not doing so - it all depends on how much it actually benefits you. Everything is a tradeoff. You don't have to use Microsoft's recommendations as they are - sure, use them as a starting point, but you should adjust them as the need arises. Not doing so can even be detrimental. You are not Microsoft, you are not facing the same needs, challenges and constraints as they are.

For example, following an externally imposed set of rules too strictly might make important concepts in your code hidden and force you to do mental gymnastics, translating between the way you think about the problem, and the way you express it in your codebase. "The industry" is not going to read your code (even if you put it on GitHub), so don't write it for "the industry", that's not your audience. That's too broad to be useful. Write it to be understandable for your team, and people who might join your team. People who are steeped in the specific problem domain you're dealing with, or are prepared to learn about it. A group of people who have their specific way of working and thinking and tackling problems. If you're writing a library for others to use, write the external API to be understandable to the target audience, and write the internals to make sense (perhaps after reading some documentation) to people who already have some idea about this problem domain.

This gives you freedom both to express ideas and concepts in code more clearly, and to structure/design your code so that it's easier to work with and maintain. Following strictly a set of rules that's not necessarily well-suited for your needs is how, very systematically and very professionally, you get a codebase that's a tangled mess.

A project that's owned and developed by a team and a project that goes from one independent developer to another have *different* constraints in terms of how widely understandable / generic their code, coding style, folder structure, logical organization, etc. should be, at the expense of how far you can go beyond simple CRUD-like behavior before you run into a wall of complexity. Tradeoffs.

---

On a more specific note, regarding internal fields: sure, `_privateField._internalField` might look strange, but that just tells you that you're not used to it. You should train yourself to be able to switch to / adopt different conventions anyway. Don't pay that much attention to the specific naming convention; instead, focus more on how the specific language feature is used, on the role it plays in your code.

You've said that you've been "using the common PascalCase for internal fields" - which is fine, but it also suggests to me that you've been, perhaps, treating internal fields more or less as public.

The internal access modifier is really just a crude, coarse-grained mechanism that allows for creating a component that spans two or three related, collaborating classes. An internal field is accessible among these classes, but should be treated as encapsulated in the overall component. It's the same old principles, just at another organizational level. You might want to do this if the class-level mechanisms can't quite express what you're trying to do, or because of considerations like performance, etc.

However, when it comes to other classes in the *same assembly* (classes that do not belong to this small collaborating cluster), this encapsulation entirely depends on (1) programmers being able to infer its there, and (2) on programmer discipline. Having an `_` as a prefix for both private and internal fields could serve as a crude workaround, a reminder that, when writing new code, you're potentially accessing a "component private" field, so that you can evaluate if such code should be refactored later on. Or it can serve as a prompt to check if there's perhaps a different way of doing the same thing that's more in line with the existing overall design.

My point is, if you adopt (or invent) a naming convention, it's a good idea to establish, as a team, some rationale behind it (or behind some of its aspects you deem relevant) that's based on the way you do work and on the needs of the project/team.

Answer (score 1):

> _myClass1._myInt = 5; just doesn't feel right to me. Maybe its because I am used to doing it other ways.

You are correct in that it doesn't feel right, because it should not. There are very few cases where internal fields are a good idea. Properties are usually a better design in general.

The argument for a `_` prefix is to easily distinguish between class-fields and local variables. If this is a sufficient issue to warrant a prefix is arguable, and opinions will almost certainly differ.

The argument for static `s_` or thread static `t_` prefixes would have a similar reasoning. I would argue for avoiding any static mutable fields as much as possible, and that would render this style moot. But one might also argue that uncommon code should have uncommon code style to alert the reader that something special is going on.

In the end the Microsoft style guidelines are written by people, and people have opinions. These opinions might differ from that of you or your team, and you should probably listen to your team more than Microsoft. Just remember to re-evaluate your coding style guidelines as the team changes. But also consider the cost of updating the coding style of an existing code-base.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal case has never been a recommendation for private fields, it has always been camel case. Pascal case is for properties, this already nicely prevents name clashes.

Adding _ or s_ serves no sensible purpose, it is a bad habit from the past that aligns with Hungarian notation which made a little sense in non-type-safe languages. Since C# is pretty type-safe, all that remains is ugly code.

So my guess is it was pushed by some really old C person who just could not kick the habit or by an unexperienced one who is unaware of the history.

Fortunately they do stress it is ultimately your choice to determine what makes sense:

> The guidelines in this article are used by Microsoft to develop
> samples and documentation. They were adopted from the .NET Runtime, C#
> Coding Style guidelines. You can use them, or adapt them to your
> needs. The primary objectives are consistency and readability within
> your project, team, organization, or company source code.

Comment: Not _just_ for type safety.  Also for situations _pre-IDE_ where you couldn't just hover over a variable and find out its access (or other attributes).  It was a marker that a field was private, or static, which you might have wanted to know without going to find the decl. (It was used quite frequently in C++ which is pretty type-safe, and was even then (compared to the alternatives)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I was moreso asking about internal fields, where I have always used PascalCase in the past, instead of _camelCase.

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote this as it is factually incorrect. R# out of the box for example recommends PascalCase for static fields. It’s a very common standard as far as I was aware until now.

Comment: @DavidArno How interesting. However, this is about C# exclusively, hence the label.

Comment: @MartinMaat, R# is ReSharper, a VS plugin that massively expands VS's C# capabilities. There's not many C# devs that I know of to be honest that haven't heard of ReSharper. So yes, this is absolutely about C# ;)

Comment: @DavidArno Resharper is not Microsoft, this is about Microsoft recommendations. Third party add-ons are not relevant.

Comment: Using an underscore prefix is no different than applying PascalCase vs camelCase for a name.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, questions about naming conventions raising a lot of discussions - this answer is another prove ;)

You can approach all questions about naming by trying to understand what is the reason behind the one or another style and based on that reason decide do you want to follow or use different one.

Usage of `_` prefix for private or internal members suggested to separate private member from local variable or input argument.

Notice that if you are using `this.` keyword to access all "internal" members, then you don't need to use `_` prefix.
That why you don't feel right about usage of internal fields outside of the class `object._field` - same as `this._field`

My suggestion: do not follow naming **guidelines** "blindly", but use it as a template and change some conventions which not serving your or your team style of writing code.